How does closing banks and foreign exchange houses prevent the curency's exchange rate from collapsing?
In Nial Ferguson´s The Ascent of Money when he describes one of the many astonishing inflation rates in Argentine, he says:
Banks and foreign exchange houses were ordered to close as the government tried to prevent the currency’s exchange rate from collapsing.
Ferguson, Niall. The Ascent of Money: A Financial History of the World: 10th Anniversary Edition (English Edition) (p. 104). Penguin Publishing Group. Edición de Kindle.
All I can think of is that closing such facilities interrupts the displays from going, sort of pausing the time or the exchange-rate activity, but I suspect other factors must be involved so, are there any other factors involved?
